"Error in Calculating Tail Value at Risk (TVaR) for Inverse Weibull Distribution: Integral Divergence Issue"
##############  ALAE Data
install.packages("evd")
library(evd)
data(package = "evd")
data(lossalae) 
attach(lossalae) 
names(lossalae) 
x <- ALAE/1000
n <- length(x) 
install.packages("fitdistrplus")
library(fitdistrplus)

# Fitting the Inverse Weibull distribution to the lossalae data using fitdist
library(actuar)
W.INV <- fitdist(x, "invweibull")
summary(W.INV)
k_inv_weibull <- length(W.INV$estimate)
loglik_inv_weibull <- W.INV$loglik
HQIC_inv_weibull <- calculate_HQIC(loglik_inv_weibull, n, k_inv_weibull)
CAIC_inv_weibull <- calculate_CAIC(loglik_inv_weibull, n, k_inv_weibull)
cat("Inverse Weibull HQIC: ", HQIC_inv_weibull, "\n")
cat("Inverse Weibull CAIC: ", CAIC_inv_weibull, "\n")
# -------------------------------------------
VarinvW1 = qinvweibull(0.7, shape = W.INV$estimate[1], scale = W.INV$estimate[2])
VarinvW1
VarinvW2 = qinvweibull(0.8, shape = W.INV$estimate[1], scale = W.INV$estimate[2])
VarinvW2
VarinvW3 = qinvweibull(0.9, shape = W.INV$estimate[1], scale = W.INV$estimate[2])
VarinvW3


integrand2 <- function(x) {
  x * dinvweibull(x, shape = W.INV$estimate[1], scale = W.INV$estimate[2])
}

Tvarinv1 = (1/(1-0.7)) * integrate(integrand2, VarinvW1, Inf, subdivisions = 1000)$value 
Tvarinv1
Tvarinv2 = (1/(1-0.8)) * integrate(integrand2, VarinvW1, Inf, subdivisions = 1000)$value
Tvarinv2
Tvarinv3 = (1/(1-0.9)) * integrate(integrand2, VarinvW1, Inf, subdivisions = 1000)$value
Tvarinv3

The error is:
Error in integrate(integrand2, VarinvW1, Inf, subdivisions = 1000) : 
  the integral is probably divergent

What did I do wrong?
I tried to increase the subdivions but it still gave me an error, what should I do to solve this problem?
